# Write code to check if s2 is a rotation of s1 using only one call to isSubstring

Tags: java, string, algorithm, stringbuffer

Assume you have a method isSubstring which checks if one word is a substring of another. Given two strings, s1 and s2, write code to check if s2 is a rotation of s1 using only one call to isSubstring

(e.g.,"waterbottle" is a rotation of "erbottlewat")

Below is my code:

```
public class IsRotation1_8 {

    /*
     * Idea: Same idea as the code in CC150 book
     * First, if the s2 is a rotation of s1, they should have the same length
     * Then, check whether the s2 is a subString of s1 + s1
     *
     * Time Complexity: O(n)
     * Space Complexity: O(n)
     */
    private static boolean isRotation(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        String s3 = s1 + s1;
        // return isSubString(s3, s2);
        return isSubString2(s3, s2);
    }

    private static boolean isSubString(String s3, String s2) {
        return s3.contains(s2);
        // return s3.indexOf(s2)!=-1;
    }

    /*
     * Implement the isSubString method without using the method of Contains and indexOf
     */
    private static boolean isSubString2(String s3, String s2){
        int lengthS3 = s3.length();
        int lengthS2 = s2.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < lengthS3; i++) {
            int j = i;
            int k = 0;
            while(s2.charAt(k++) == s3.charAt(j++)){
                if(k == lengthS2)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter string1 (q to quit):");

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String string1 = input.nextLine();
            if (string1.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("quit...");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            System.out.println("Please enter string2:");
            String string2 = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Is s2 a rotation of s1?(solution1) :"
                    + isRotation(string1, string2));
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Please enter another string1 (q to quit): ");
        }
    }
}
```

It implements the Questions well, But I have some questions about it

1. I don't know how to calculate the Time Complexity for this solution, it seems depends on the isSubString method, what's the time complexity of the String.contains() method?
2. If I use my own isSubString method instead of the String.contains() method, does the time complexity be O(n) even though there are two-loops here
3. A friend told me that O(n) if using String, O(1) if using StringBuilder, not counting the time of the isSubstring() method, is that right? Can someone specific explain about it?

I know the String is immutable, and StringBuffer is mutable, and when using a String, every time when add a character or doing some operation, it will create a new String, but the Stringbuffer will not.

But I don't think it will influence the time complexity. 
in this solution, even using the String, it just product a new String

Comment: The typical case is O(n) but the worst case is O(n^2) whether you use your method, the built in one or StringBuffer/StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Java's documentation doesn't constrain the implementation of `String.contains` to use a specific algorithm. If the algorithm is, e.g., Knuth--Morris--Pratt, then the running time would be linear. If the algorithm is the naive one, then the running time would be quadratic.
2. `isSubString2` implements the naive algorithm, which is worst-case quadratic.
3. Ignoring optimization, each `String` concatenation has cost equal to the length of the combined string, but each `StringBuilder` append has (amortized) cost equal to the length of the appended string. A single `String` concatenation, as you use here, is always linear-time, but it's wise to switch to a `StringBuilder` for repeated appends, to avoid repaying the cost of the first characters many times over.

Comment: 1-2: If the requirement is: don't use the String.contains(1.5) and String.indexOf(before 1.5), which means I should use the KMP to implement this Q? how about the Boyer-Moore algorithm. I'm been told the BM algorithm is 3-5 times fast than the KMP.

Comment: @jyuan Is your goal to get a good asymptotic worst-case or to run fast on non-pathological inputs?

Comment: This is a interview Q, so I think what I need to do is to make the algorithm more efficient and less complexity.

Comment: @jyuan What you need to do is ask the interviewer questions to elicit the additional requirements that would allow you to make an appropriate choice.